# pyqtgraph DataTreeWidget show lines like QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

QTableWidget has lines that looks like a spreadsheet. DataTreeWidget doesn't show lines. Is there a way to add lines to a pyqtgraph DataTreeWidget that displays nested dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

DataTreeWidget is just a thin subclass of QTreeWidget, so you're more likely to get answers looking there. For example:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/55363-QTreeView-and-Column-Row-Gridlines